# Disable inlay type hints for literals in Pylance?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

The inlay type hints in Pylance is great and helps with legacy code. However, type hints for literals clutter up the editor with no new information.

[image: clutter up the editor with no new information]

For Enums, this is especially annoying.

[image: this is especially annoying.]

Is there a way to disable type hints in only these scenarios?

I could not find more settings than

```
"python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": true,
"python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": true,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no option available at the moment for disabling this feature only for literals. Inlay Type Hints with plylance is recently released and it only provides [following two types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-july-2022-release/#inlay-type-hints).

> In this release, we have added ***two types of inlay hints*** when using
> Pylance: for variable types and for return types.
>
> Return type inlay hints show the return types of functions that don’t
> have an explicit annotation. To enable it, you can set
> “`python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes`”: true to your user
> settings (Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) command).
>
> Similarly, variable type inlay hints show the types of variables that
> don’t have explicit type annotations. You can enable it by setting
> “`python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes”: true`.

May be you can submit a feature request/issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release)